# In Swift, drawRect for custom view is not updating properly

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, drawrect

Below is my drawRect function for a simple custom view.  When I use

```
var h: CGFloat = 200
```

the view displays itself properly: a rectangle part of which is black, part of which is red.  But when I use

```
var h: CGFloat = fractionalHeight*parentViewHeight
```

all I get is a black rectangle.  If `fractionalHeight` (a property of the view)
is 0.5, half of the rectangle should be red. The print statement confirms the fact
that h is what I think it should be.  Hmmmmm?  What's going on?

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

    let parentViewBounds = self.bounds
    let parentViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(parentViewBounds)
    let parentViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(parentViewBounds)
    println ("w,h = \(parentViewWidth),\(parentViewHeight) ")

    // CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1); // black
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, parentViewWidth, parentViewHeight));

    println("in drawRect, fractionalHeight = \(fractionalHeight)")

    var h: CGFloat = 200 // fractionalHeight*parentViewHeight

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1); // red
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, parentViewWidth, h))
    println("in drawRect, h = \(h)")

}
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  How do you have `fractionalHeight` declared?  I used `var fractionalHeight: CGFloat = 0.5`.

Comment: Yes, I have `class OCIndicator: UIView {`, then `var fractionalHeight: Float` declaring the property.

Comment: Where are you setting `fractionalHeight` to `0.5`?

Comment: I'm setting in `viewDidLoad:                         
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        var indicator: OCIndicator = OCIndicator(frame: CGRectMake(10, 30, 50, 400))
       
        self.view.addSubview(indicator)
        self.indicator.fractionalHeight = 0.5
        
        println("indicator.fractionalHeight = \(self.indicator.fractionalHeight)")
        self.indicator.setNeedsDisplay()
        
    }`

Comment: The initialization code for the indicator object sets the property fractionalHeight to zero.  Later, in viewDidLoad, I set it to 0.5 and call setNeedsDisplay on indicator.  I've found that if I set it to 0.5 in the initialization code, it displays properly.  But of course I want to be able to reset it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are talking to 2 different OCIndicator instances.

I believe you have an OCIndicator (in your StoryBoard perhaps) hooked up to an IBOutlet in your `ViewController`.

In `viewDidLoad` you are creating a second instance of OCIndicator and assigning it to the local variable `indicator` and you are adding that to your `subView` which is covering up the first one.  But then, you are setting `fractionalHeight` on `self.indicator` which is not the same indicator and you are telling that one that it needs to display, but it has been covered up by the one added in `viewDidLoad`.

So, get rid of:

```
var indicator: OCIndicator = OCIndicator(frame: CGRectMake(10, 30, 50, 400))
self.view.addSubview(indicator)
```

from `viewDidLoad` and see how that works.

Comment: @vacawama Could you help me with my drawRect issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855349/make-2-contradictory-methods-work-in-drawrect